# What song from Wu-Tang is this?

Tags: identify-this-song, rap

In a song from the Wu-Tang Clan near the beginning there is a line *said* by one of the rappers "da fuq" as though to imply that (possibly) the track had skipped.

I have looked but have not found it.

Does anyone know the song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wu Tang Clan song [*Wu Tang: 7th Chamber*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OR85Vbbnj4), from the album *Enter the 36 Chambers*, has an intro dialogue between several members saying several times lines like

> Where the f*ck!

or

> What the f*ck!

or even

> the f*ck off!